# How to install cgroup man pages on Fedora?

Tags: fedora, man, cgroups

I want to install [cgroup man pages](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/cgroups.7.html) on Fedora, but I can't find any package that contains it.

Comment: What does `dnf provides '*/cgroups.7.*'` show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**They're in `man-pages`, so you might have them already.**

```
$ dnf -C provides '*/cgroups.7.gz'
man-pages-5.04-4.fc32.noarch : Linux kernel and C library user-space interface documentation
Repo        : updates
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/share/man/man7/cgroups.7.gz
```